# $id is not found in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to show information for one user in database. The query is working fine when I put a static value for the user id into the where statement:

```
where('radcheck.username', '=', '5345855');
```

but when I turned it to dynamic  it not working and the error $id not found is appear

```
where('radcheck.username', '=', $id);
```

I dont know why I can not see the `$id` because if I write `echo $id` it is printed successfully. This is the code of the controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    echo $id;
    $result = DB::table('radcheck')
        -> leftJoin('radreply', function ($join) {
            $join->on('radcheck.username', '=', 'radreply.username')
                ->where('radcheck.username', '=',$id);
        })
        ->select(
            'radcheck.username',
            DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' then radcheck.value end) as password"),
            DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Expiration' then radcheck.value end) as expiration"),
            DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'ChilliSpot-Max-Total-Octets' then radcheck.value end) as quta"),
            DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Simultaneous-Use' then radcheck.value end) as simul"),
            DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Max-All-Session' then radcheck.value end) as session"),
            DB::raw("max(case when radreply.attribute = 'WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up' then radreply.value end) as upload"),
            DB::raw("max(case when radreply.attribute = 'WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down' then radreply.value end) as download"),
            DB::raw("max(radcheck.adsoyad) as realname"),
            DB::raw("min(radcheck.dtarih) as birthdate"),
            DB::raw("min(radcheck.telefon) as phone"),
            DB::raw("min(radcheck.tcno) as tc"),
            DB::raw("max(radcheck.email) as email"),
            DB::raw("min(radcheck.id) as id")
        )
        ->get();

    return response()->json(['data' => $result]);
}
```

This is my route definition:

```
Route::resource('users', 'radcheckController');
```

I send data using ajax and this is my ajax code:

```
$('.edit-user').on('click', function() {
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/users/' + id,
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        },
        success: function(hr_request) {
            alert(hr_request);
            var obj=hr_request.data['0'];
            alert(obj['username']);

            $('#username').val(obj['username']);
            $('#password').val(obj['password']);
            $('#realname').val(obj['realname']);
            $('#mobile').val(obj['phone']);
            $('#email').val(obj['email']);
            $('#birthdate').val(obj['birthdate']);
            $('#simul').val(obj['simul']);
            $('#tc').val(obj['tc']);$('#email').val(obj['email']);
            $('#date_expir').val(obj['expiration']);
            $('#quta').val(obj['quta']/1024/1024);
            $('#sessiontime').val(obj['session']/60);
            $('#edit-modal-label').html('Edit Selected Row');
            $('#addModal').modal('show')
        },
        error: function(hr_request) {
            console.log(hr_request['username']) ;
        }
    });
});
```

So my question is, why does the query not recognize the `$id`?

Comment: post your route and html

Comment: I edited my question @RahulShrivastava

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code that may works

```
      public function show($id)
       {

       echo $id;
        $result = DB::table('radcheck')-> leftJoin('radreply', function 
       ($join) use($id) {
        $join->on('radcheck.username', '=', 'radreply.username')
              ->where('radcheck.username', '=',$id);
          }) ->select('radcheck.username', 
       DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' then 
        radcheck.value end) as password"),
DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Expiration' then radcheck.value end) as expiration"),
DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'ChilliSpot-Max-Total-Octets' then radcheck.value end) as quta"),
DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Simultaneous-Use' then radcheck.value end) as simul"),
DB::raw("max(case when radcheck.attribute = 'Max-All-Session' then radcheck.value end) as session"),
    DB::raw("max(case when radreply.attribute = 'WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up' then radreply.value end) as upload"),
DB::raw("max(case when radreply.attribute = 'WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down' then radreply.value end) as download"),
DB::raw("max(radcheck.adsoyad) as realname"),
DB::raw("min(radcheck.dtarih) as birthdate"),
DB::raw("min(radcheck.telefon) as phone"),
DB::raw("min(radcheck.tcno) as tc"),
DB::raw("max(radcheck.email) as email"),
DB::raw("min(radcheck.id) as id")
)

    ->get();

return response()->json(['data' => $result]);
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to post and saw your answer with the same.

Comment: thank you  for reply but it not working and when I add  console.log( response()->json(['data' => $result]));  the console undefined error display

Comment: Ok then how the $id works without passing in use function?

Comment: The answer lacks an explanation, which is actually way more valuable than a working code snippet. Reason is that only an explanation will help other readers with a similar (but not the very same) problem in future, whilst a working snippet does not.

Comment: it worked successfully when I writing the url http://localhost:8000/users/324234123    and it returned {"data":[{"username":"324234123","password":null,"expiration":null}]}  but I can not retrieve data from ajax code

Comment: it worked successfully thankyou very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

Need to pass the variable inside the function using `use` keyword, then only it can be accessed inside it.

Like that:

```
$result = DB::table('radcheck')-> leftJoin('radreply', function 
   ($join) use ($id) { // Notice `use ($id)` here.....
    $join->on('radcheck.username', '=', 'radreply.username')
          ->where('radcheck.username', '=', $id);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define any dynamic variables in your routes:

```
Route::resource('users','radcheckController');
```

To access variables in controllers, you have to define them in routes first:

```
Route::resource('users/{id}','radcheckController');
```

Then you can access to `$id` variable in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the necessary variables from the parent scope into the closure with the use keyword.

In your case change this line

```
    $result = DB::table('radcheck')-> leftJoin('radreply', function 
   ($join) {
```

to this

```
$result = DB::table('radcheck')-> leftJoin('radreply', function 
   ($join) use ($id) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check route
 and use this route
 and no need any token for get url

Route::get('users/{id}', 'radcheckController@show');

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the variables from the parent scope into the closure with the use keyword. In your case you forgot to pass $id

Example:

```
$result = DB::table('radcheck')-> leftJoin('radreply', function 
   ($join) use ($id) {
    $join->on('radcheck.username', '=', 'radreply.username')
          ->where('radcheck.username', '=', $id);
      })
```